# Vector norm such that $\| (1,i) \| = 6$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

> Is there a norm $\| \cdot \|: \mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $\bigg\| \pmatrix{1\\i} \bigg\| = 6$?

I have come across this question and I don't really know what to look for here. Trying out random norms to see if one of them give $6$ doesn't look like a good idea, and I can't think of any properties of norms that the function in the example would not obey to prove such norm doesn't exist.

Comment: Do you mean $\Bbb C^2$?

Comment: @edm yes, edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
$$\Vert x \Vert = 3\sqrt{x^H x}$$
where $x^H$ is the transpose - conjugation operation, i.e. Hermitian operator. This norm satisfies the three basic norm properties, i.e.

1. $ \Vert x \Vert = 0 $ only if $x  = 0$
2. For $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$,$ \Vert \alpha x \Vert = 3\sqrt{(\alpha x)^H \alpha x} = 3 \sqrt{ \vert \alpha \vert^2 x^H x } = \vert \alpha \vert 3\sqrt{  x^H x } = \vert \alpha \vert \Vert x \Vert$
3. $ \Vert x + y \Vert \leq \Vert x  \Vert + \Vert  y \Vert $

Comment: Wouldn' t that norm be zero with $\pmatrix{1\\i}$?

Comment: Nope $x^H x = 2$ where $x = \pmatrix{1\\i}$. I think you forgot to do conjugate.

Comment: Ohh all right! By the way how did you come to that answer? I mean thinking of a function that is both a norm and gives the desired value for a given vector. Seems like magic to me...

Comment: Haha @Yagger .. You read more, you get to know more. No magic to it, believe me. I know about the complex inner product and i just scaled it. That's all I did

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer

Comment: no problem @Yagger

Answer (score 4):

Hint: if $\| \cdot \|$ is a norm, then so is $c \| \cdot \|$ for any constant $c > 0$.

Comment: Thanks! That also kind of answers the question I posted below